# How to go underline every 2 words when using explode?

Tags: php

I don't know how to go underline every two words when using explode.

```php
<?php
$original_sentence = "Rayane,Jack,John,Kriss,Bob,Steph";
$words = explode(",", $original_sentence);
shuffle($words);
echo implode(",",$words);
?>
```

I want to go underline at the name Jack and after that show 2 next names and go underline again. Like this :

```
Rayane,Jack, 
John,Kriss,
Bob,Steph
```

Comment: Provide expected output, please

Comment: Added the output example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
 <?php
$original_sentence = "Rayane,Jack,John,Kriss,Bob,Steph";
$explode_array = explode(',',$original_sentence);
//For randomizes the order of the elements in the array use shuffle
shuffle($explode_array);
$array = array_chunk($explode_array,2);
foreach($array as $value){
    echo implode(',', $value) .'<br>';
}
?>
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/LiU7d)

Comment: I just got another question, what if I want to randomize? Put rayane not with jack but Kris for example.

Comment: @M3ren, I update the code for related comments, Please check